# Categories and page filtering with pre_get_posts

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, loop

I have 3 pages, "Page 1" shows custom post-type "articles", "Page 2" shows custom post-type "tips", and "Page 3" shows both custom post-types. This is done conditionally with a custom loop in `page.php`.

Both post-types have the default "category" taxonomy as well as an extra custom taxonomy for each type.

When you're on a page and click on the category link associated to a post you go to `/category/cat/`. My current `category.php` template pulls in both "articles" and "tips" that match that category. What I want to do is if you click on the category when you're on 'Page 1" then only show "articles" in the category template, if you're on "Page 2" then only show "tips". And on "Page 3" show both.

I've been trying to do this with `pre_get_posts` but I'm not sure how to implement it. Should I create different templates for each page? Should I just POST an extra variable and modify the query in `category.php`? Any ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Please Consider this snippets of code.

---

```
<?php 
     $myarticles = new WP_Query( 'post_type=myarticles&orderby=date&order=DESC&cat=4' );    
         while ($myarticles->have_posts()) : $myarticles->the_post();
                $postTitle = get_the_title();
            $postid = get_the_id();
        $postContent    = get_the_content();
?>

 <li><p><?php echo $postTitle;  ?></p>
<a href="#"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(219,143)); ?></a> 
                  <p><?php echo $postContent;  ?></p>
 </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```